# How can I use resource objects (via promises) with D3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, font-awesome

**UPDATE:** I realized that trying to perform the database lookups this late in the game was poor form -- I updated my code so that my raw data coming into D3 already included the information I would need to create my graph and everything works as expected.

I'm trying to build a force-directed graph that performs a database lookup on node elements to get additional information regarding the node for further customization in the graph.

In the below example, I am trying to use FontAwesome glyphs to create 'icons' for my nodes. Right now, in my `getIcon()` function, I correctly draw the node icon/glyph IF and ONLY IF I return the unicode value right away. Once I put a promise in and wait to return the value, things break. D3 is constructing and rendering the graph before the promise has a chance to return. How can I make `.text(getIcon)` wait to append text (a glyph icon) to a node until after we've resolved my promise?

```
node.append('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
  .style('font-family','FontAwesome')
  .style('font-size','24px')
  .text(getIcon)
  .style('fill', function (d) {
    return color(d.group);
  });
```

`getIcon()` is defined as follows:

```
function getIcon(d) {
  myPromise.then(function(data) {
    if(data.value) {
      return '\uf108';
    } else { return '\uf233'; }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you declare the promise?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your promise because your not using `d` and you haven't shared the declaration of your promise, but maybe this is the type of structure you need...

```
node.append('text')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
    .style('font-family','FontAwesome')
    .style('font-size','24px')
    .each(getIcon)
    .style('fill', function (d) {
        return color(d.group);
    });
function getIcon(d) {
    var node = this;
    var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        d3.json("data.json", function(error, glyphs){
            if(error || glyphs[d.char] === "undefined") reject('\uf233'); else resolve(glyphs[d.glyph]);
        })
    });
    myPromise.then(function(glyph) {
        d3.select(node).text(glyph)
    }).catch(function(defaultGlyph){
        d3.select(node).text(defaultGlyph)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While i have never worked on D3, but i think you need to call getIcon first and then do the node.append logic in the promise callback. Something like

```
getIcon().then(function(data) {
   node.append('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
  .style('font-family','FontAwesome')
  .style('font-size','24px')
  .text(data)
  .style('fill', function (d) {
    return color(d.group);
  });
});
```

But i realize that the `d` parameter then will be unavailable.

Comment: My lookup is dependent on ```d``` being available :(